# How can I switch displaying items and figures from 2 columns without overwriting the previously displayed stuffs in beamer?

Tags: beamer, presentations

Well I am making a beamer presentation and in one of the frames I am using two columns. The code actually looks like the following

```
    \begin{frame}{$Z_1=Z_4$}
    \begin{columns}
    \column{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \tiny
    \item Let the event $E$ denote ``$S_0[1]=2$, $S_0[2]\notin \{-1,0,1\}$, $S_0[3]= N-3$ or $N-5$''.
    \item Then we have the following transitions.
    \item $S_1[1]=X$, $X\notin \{-1,0,1\}$,$S_1[2]=2$.
    \item $Z_1=S_1[X+2]$.
    \item The following transitions take place in next 3 rounds.
    \item We have, $Z_4=S_4[X+2]$.
    \item If $X\notin \{-1,0,1\}$, the indices $i,j$ never touches the value $X+2$ in the first 4 rounds.
    \item Hence the value at the index location $X+2$ never gets swapped out.
    \end{itemize}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/fig1.pdf}
        \onslide<2>\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/fig2.pdf}
        \onslide<3>\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/fig3.pdf}
        \onslide<4>\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/fig4.pdf}
        \onslide<5->\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img/fig5.pdf}
        \end{overprint}
    \end{figure}
    \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
```

The frame looks like the following

[image: A screenshot of the frame]

**What I need** is after displaying the first 2 items, I want the images from second column to be displayed up to fig2.pdf. Then switch back to the first column and display the next 3 items. Then start displaying rest of the figures (from fig3.pdf to fig5.pdf) and finally display the remaining items from first column. **And most importantly** I don't want any stuff, which are already displayed, to disappear or overwritten.

I am new to beamer so I understand that I maybe over-looking or over-explaining stuffs. So any help regarding this issue would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You control the order of what is displayed when on the slide with the argument of `<>`. This can for some functions be given as an optional argument, such as `\item<3>`, but can also be given as `\onslide<3>{Content on slide 3}`. The argument tells beamer on which slide(s) to the contents should be shown and can be given as a single page `<3>`, an interval `<2-4>´, or show up on page and stay`<3->´. So you can stat by showing the first bullets by using

```
\item<1-> Some text
\item<2-> Some text
```

Then some images

```
\onslide<3->{\includegraphics[...]{picture}}
```

and then continue the bullets

```
\item<4-> Some text
```

Since I don't know much of the format of your slide set I made an alternative example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-2> On slide 1 and 2
  \item<2-> On slide 2 and all the rest
  \item<4-> On slide 4 
  \end{itemize}
  \onslide<3->{Picture on slide 3 and the rest
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first item still disappears. I want the already displayed items to still hold the screen.

Comment: The above example tries to show how `<>` can be used. For the first bullet it states `<1-2>`, meaning it should be visible on slide 1 to 2. Change to `<1->` if you want it to appear on slide 1 and be present on all successive slides.

Comment: To get a feeling of what `<>` does, try to play around with the numbers on different places. Try different versions of `<2->`, `<2>` and `<-2>` and see what happens. Just for fun, you can try `<20>`. (That of course depends on what you mean by fun:-)

Comment: Figured it out :)